# Why does Alice not use this power aggressively?

Tags: october-faction

We've seen that Alice has the power to do...something where she can move about unseen while everyone and everything else appears frozen. Although it's not clear what this power is, it could be a burst of extreme speed, since her hair is always blowing around. In this state, she appears to be able to interact with other objects, since, for instance, she was able to flip someone's phone around in midair.

However, whenever we've seen her in combat, she has used her telekinetic or mind-control powers, which although quite powerful seem much more limited. Further, we have only seen her use her time-stop or speed power for reconnaissance. What, if anything, prevents Alice from employing this power in a more aggressive manner in actual combat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible answer: Director's choice. If she used that power all the time, there would be little for the MC's to stop her and even get a chance to talk to her.

I haven't read the comics to see how she is depicted there, but she probably doesn't use that power when she wants to speak to other persons or to simply demonstrate to others what she is capable of.

Hope a more conclusive answer shows up from someone who read the comics.